# pivot table in PHP

Tags: php, pivot

```
Chromosome  Locus       Variant_A   Variant_B   Variant Strain_ID   Family  Parent1_Name    Parent1_Marker  Parent2_Name    Parent2_Marker  Line    Marker  Gid
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gm09        40907915    G           A           GA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      BB      2
Gm09        422384      G           A           GA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      4
Gm09        422720      A           G           AG      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      BB      5
Gm09        424439      C           A           CA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      7
Gm09        425375      G           T           GT      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      9
Gm09        425581      T           C           TC      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      BB      10
Gm09        43921862    C           A           CA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      AA      12
```

I've the table shown above. I need the following output:

```
    | Strain     |           | Gm09_40907915 | Gm09_422384 | Gm09_422720 | Gm09_424439 |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant_A | G             | G           | A           | C           |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant_B | A             | A           | G           | A           |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant   | GA            | GA          | AG          |        CA    |  |
```

+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------

The problem here is that I can't use pivot in sql server as the number of columns is more than the maximum limit. I get the input table from a sql server query and I need to format it in PHP. After reading a bit, I was able to understand how to do it for simple tables. But I'm not sure how to proceed for the complex table I've. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 The table is stored in a variable like this and is stored in a retrieved into a variable in PHP. 

     $tsql =  select  * from genotypeQA

     $params = array( $_REQUEST['query'] );

    $getProducts = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql,$params);
```

I need to format(Pivot) the table in $getProducts in PHP